# Permission to execute Mulesoft Anypoint Access Management APIs

Tags: api, permissions, anypoint-studio

I am using internal mulesoft APIs from Anypoint Access Management [API Reference](https://anypoint.mulesoft.com/apiplatform/anypoint-platform/#/portals/organizations/68ef9520-24e9-4cf2-b2f5-620025690913/apis/11270/versions/11646/pages/11245). I have successfully setup my postman to get the security token after login, and even executed successfully the /api/users/me and several other APIs as API creation, Portal creation, etc. However, regardless of the access provided to the connection/login user, i can't get the full list of users (/api/users) or full list of organizations (/api/organizations), receiving a 401-Not authorized error. What special permission does the connection user require to execute these 2 APIs? 
Thank in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue but figured it out.

Instead of calling: `/api/users`, you should be calling `https://anypoint.mulesoft.com/accounts/api/organizations/{orgId}/members` to get a list of users.